# Using Beta.Select function in R (prior estimate)

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I am trying to formulate the priors by using total counts and beta distribution.

I have following written:

```
quantile(df$row, probs=c(0.00001, 0.5, 0.99999))

quantile1 <- list(p=0.5, x=8)
quantile2 <- list(p=0.99999, x=10)
quantile3 <- list(p=0.00001, x=1)

library("LearnBayes")
findBeta <- function(quantile1,quantile2,quantile3)

quantile1_p <- quantile1[[1]]; quantile1_q <- quantile1[[2]]
quantile2_p <- quantile2[[1]]; quantile2_q <- quantile2[[2]]
quantile3_p <- quantile3[[1]]; quantile3_q <- quantile3[[2]]

priorA <- beta.select(list(p=0.5, x=8), list(p=0.99999, x=10))
```

and once I am trying to calculate priorA using beta.select function I get following error:

```
Error in if (p0 < p) m.hi = m0 else m.lo = m0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In pbeta(x, K * m0, K * (1 - m0)) : NaNs produced
```

I just can't get rid of the error and do not know how to approach it any more. Urgently need help.

Comment: what is `df`?  perhaps a `dput(df)` ?

Comment: For the beta distribution values should be between 0 and <1. In your example 0.5 quantile is x=8 and 0.9999 quantile is x=10 -  so you get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing (completely out of thin air) that you are dealing with percentages.  In which case you want to use `x/100`

```
beta.select(list(p=0.5, x=.08), list(p=0.9, x=.10))
#  [1]  28.02 318.74
```

---

Either way, while it would be nice of `beta.select` to throw a more appropriate error message (or rather, to have an error check in there), the root of the issue is that your `x`'s are out of bounds.  (As @Didzis noted, the interval for a beta dist is `[0, 1]`)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it. Since I was using Beta distribution as a fit, I had to recalculate Bayesian distribution for occurance. Some where in the loop, beta.select function was either estimating negative values or values higher than 1, which is not possible for the distribution.          

Thank you for the response.